# Disable the possibility to hide notifications in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Since Android Lollipop, the user can hide notifications of an application from Android settings.
I'm writing a parental control application and I'm searching for a way to disable this functionality.
Indeed, I want notifications to be always displayed, even if the child doesn't want to see them.

I saw that on tablets (not on phones) we can create a specific profile to block access to the settings app, but I don't want to lock the settings app, and the trick needs to work on phones too.
I also looked in manifest file to see if an option was there to explicitly enable/disable this but I found nothing.

Please note that my app does have admin privileges.

After hours of head scratching and hundred of coffees, nothing came to me from Android developer website or any other website, I'm desparated.
So finally, is there a way to disable the possibility to hide notifications in Android Lollipop?

Comment: To my knowledge, what you specifically ask (which is to allow a notification from an application that has this particular setting turned off in the Android system's settings) NO you cannot.

Comment: Hi Nicolas

I saw that you closed the question "With Flutter, audio_service and firestore, I have a fatal NullPointerException Unable to stop service com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService".

Did you manage to fix the problem? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the ability to hide unwanted notification would be undoing what that feature is. As far as I know there is no way to do that.

**EDIT:**
However - there is an broadcast send after each settings change (WiFi turn on / off etc.). Some settings blocking apps are using this to revert changes made before entering password - maybe there is an intent that does the same for hiding notification.